Running kiosk-website on Raspberry Pi keeps loading cached (old) videos
I have a Raspberry Pi 4 with Raspberry Pi OS installed. I want to use it as a kiosk-Terminal to display some video that will be updated with new information on a regular base. The video file is stored on a network drive that will be mounted under /mnt/Drive_P/.
It's working well besides the fact that it keeps showing the same video after a refresh, no matter if I replace the mp4-file or even delete it. It always requires a reboot to actually load the new material!
I have the following shell-script in the autostart:
firefox "file:///mnt/Drive_P/Kiosk/VideoViewer.html?Kiosk/Videos/Test.mp4" -kiosk -new-window

And this is the code of my VideoViewer.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>VideoViewer</title>
    
    <script>
        function BodyOnLoad()
        {
            var URL = location.href;
            var Extension = URL.split("?")[1];
            
            window.setInterval(CheckVideoTimer, 10000);
            document.getElementById("VideoPlayerSourceMP4").src="/mnt/Drive_P/" + Extension;
            document.getElementById("VideoPlayer").addEventListener('ended', VideoEnded, false);
            document.getElementById("VideoPlayer").load();
        }
        
        function VideoEnded(e)
        {
            <!-- Instead of looping the video I want to reload the page so it should load the latest video file again -->
            location.reload();
        }
        
        function CheckVideoTimer()
        {
            var Vid = document.getElementById("VideoPlayer");
            
            if ((Vid.paused && (Vid.duration == Vid.currentTime)) || (Vid.readyState == 0))
            {
                <!-- there is no video-file at the given location, reload and try again -->
                location.reload();
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="BodyOnLoad()">
    <video id="VideoPlayer" width="100%" height="100%" autoplay preload="none">
        <source id="VideoPlayerSourceMP4" src="" type="video/mp4">
        Your browser does not support the video tag.
    </video>
</body>

I found many older threads about reloading a page without cached contents by using "location.reload(true);" but this sadly does not work any longer.

The usual workaround to add a cache buster via the query string, won't work here, because you are accessing this via the file protocol. And I doubt any caching instructions applied to the document itself via meta tags would help either.

Did you try adding console.log() to see if it executes the code where you have placed location.reload() ?

I have realized it is not a problem with the browser cache but rather how the Raspberry Pi caches network files itself. When I copy the file from my mounted drive to a local folder, e.g. my video folder, the website behaves just as I want it to.
